# How can I capture an image using ARCore Camera with objects?

Tags: android, kotlin, augmented-reality, arcore, sceneform

I am creating an application using ARCore to display some images on blank surface. I want to capture image of that surface where object is display. I have put a capture button on AR camera screen.

Is it possible to capture that view with objects in ARCore camera?

Comment: check this https://gptshubham595.medium.com/unveiling-the-world-of-ar-with-arcore-my-journey-of-exploration-practical-guide-86ac7f54b34

Answer (score 3):

If you simply need a screenshot of the ARCore view you can try using some Android functionality such as `PixelCopy.request(view, bitmap, (copyResult)->{})` on the ArSceneView of the ARCore fragment.

Source: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/sceneform-intro/index.html?index=..%2F..io2018#15

Comment: what if not just a snapshot, how to capturing a high res image just like native camera app?

Comment: This will also include the ARCore and/ or Sceneform nodes on it as well