# How to capture ARCore screen with objects? (Not a duplicate)

Tags: android, opengl-es, augmented-reality, arcore

With the latest ARCore SDK (version 1.27.0) it is not possible to capture screen/ surface with solutions given on [PixelCopy solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53913727/how-can-i-capture-an-image-using-arcore-camera-with-objects)/ [PixelCopy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58665513/how-can-i-take-screenshots-using-arcore) as SceneForm is deprecated.

How to capture the content of GLSurfaceView?

Answer (score 1):

Sceneform is dead long live Sceneform Maintained :)
I'm working with the SceneForm Maintained Branch and I can confirm that the PixelCopy-Method is still working with ArCore 1.26.0. The reason why I havn't updated to 1.27.0 is a bug in ArCore regarding the face recognition feature.

- [Sceneform Maintained Android SDK](https://github.com/ThomasGorisse/sceneform-android-sdk): Based on Sceneform with latest compatibly and functionalities from Android (including androidx**), ARCore and Filament. Currently a small community is working on it to keep it up to date and to develop new features.

If you want to know more about the community maintained version of Sceneform check out this [Medium Article](https://medium.com/make-an-android-ar-augmented-reality-app-for/make-an-ar-augmented-reality-app-for-android-in-2022-48a1711562bb)